# How do I randomize the starting direction of a ball in Spritekit?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I've started trying a few things with SpriteKit for Game Development. I was creating a brick breaking game. So I've run into a issue on how to randomize the starting direction of the ball.

My ball has the following properties

```
ball.physicsBody.friction = 0;
ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0;
ball.physicsBody.restitution = 1 ; //energy lost on impact or bounciness
```

To start at different direction during the gameplay, I've randomized the selection of the 4 vectors because I'm using the `applyImpulse` method to direct the ball in a particular direction and I need to make sure the ball does not go slow if the vector values are low.

```
int initialDirection = arc4random()%10;
CGVector myVector;

if(initialDirection < 2)
{
    myVector = CGVectorMake(4, 7);
}
else if(initialDirection >3 && initialDirection <= 6)
{
    myVector = CGVectorMake(-7, -5);
}
else if(initialDirection >6 && initialDirection <= 8)
{
     myVector = CGVectorMake(-5, -8);
}
else
{
     myVector = CGVectorMake(8, 5);
}
//apply the vector
[ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:myVector];
```

Is this the right way to do it? I tried using `applyForce` method but then, ball slowed down after the force was applied.

Is there any way I can randomize the direction and still maintain a speed for my ball ?

Comment: Hey! Nice to meet you here man!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I thought we had once met here long ago! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic steps

1. Randomly select an angle in [0, 2*PI)
2. Select the magnitude of the impulse
3. Form vector by converting magnitude/angle to vector components

Here's an example of how to do that

**ObjC:**

```
CGFloat angle = arc4random_uniform(1000)/1000.0 * M_PI_2; 
CGFloat magnitude = 4;
CGVector vector = CGVectorMake(magnitude*cos(angle), magnitude*sin(angle));

[ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:vector];
```

**Swift**

```
let angle:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(1000)/1000) * (CGFloat.pi/2)
let magnitude:CGFloat = 4

let vector = CGVector(x:magnitude * cos(angle), y:magnitude * sin(angle))
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)
```